# Subfigures. To add A and B to subfigures (in the top left corner), and to label them for referencing

Tags: cross-referencing, subfloats

I'm trying to set up a figure, so that it contains 2 subfigures. I would prefer if I could set them up with an A and B in the left-top corner (outside of the figure). However, I would also want to be able to reference each subfigure in my text. I have searched for a lot of different solutions, but I haven't been able to put together anything that works, so I'll try with a question.

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book} 
\usepackage{subcaption} 
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} 
\usepackage{cleveref} 

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[tb]
\centering

\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.03\textwidth}
    \textbf{A}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=t]{"test1"}
    \label{subfigure1}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.03\textwidth}
    \textbf{B}  
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=t]{"test1"}
    \label{subfigure2}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{Here's a nice caption}. \label{overall label}
\end{figure}

Me trying to reference the entire figure: Figure \ref{overall label}. 
Me trying to reference the first subfigure A: Figure \cref{subfigure1}.
Me trying to reference the first subfigure B: Figure \cref{subfigure2}.
\end{document}
```

It looks something like this

[image: Subfigure reference problem]

I think I've got the part covered with the letters (even though I have to manually assign the letters). However, I can not get the subfigure reference to work.

I'm sorry if it seems messy. I'm not particularly adept with LaTeX. I hope someone will be able to help out!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! See if   http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20354/sidesubfloats-why-does-this-errored-code-work-and-my-correct-code-doesnt solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you like to have something like this:

[image]

It is adopted from answer [sidesubfloats](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20354/sidesubfloats-why-does-this-errored-code-work-and-my-correct-code-doesnt):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[label font=bf,labelformat=simple]{subfig}% <-- changed
\usepackage{caption}
\floatsetup[figure]{style=plain,subcapbesideposition=top}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htb]\centering
\sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-a}\label{fig:a}}
\hfil
\sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-b}\label{fig:b}}
\caption{Main caption}
    \label{fig:myfigure}
    \end{figure}
Figure \ref{fig:myfigure} consist three sub figures: \ref{fig:a} and \ref{fig:b}     
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
Sub captuion layout you can determine by `subfig` options. They are summarized in `subfig` documentation, page 8. If you replace

```
\usepackage{subfig}
```

with

```
\usepackage[label font=bf,labelformat=simple]{subfig}
```

than subcaptions will look as show new image.

Comment: Excellent answer! It solves many of my problems. I, however, have a new one: Will it be possible to change the labeling of my subfigures from (a) and (b) to a bold-fontet A and B? And also make this appear in my text when I reference them? So it says "Figure 1 consists three subfigures: 1A and 1B"?

Comment: well, this is additional/new question ... :-). of course, it is possible. See `subfig` documentations for options which it offer. I can do this latter evening.

Comment: That would be much appreciated! I have checked the documentations for both floatrow and subfig, I now know how to make the captions bold, but not how to get rid of the parenthesis and make it capital letters.

Comment: The `\usepackage[label font=bf,labelformat=simple]{subfig}` did the trig, I will upgrade my answer.

Comment: Is there any way to adjust the size of the letters a and b, while maintaining the bold font?

Comment: Yes, it is. I look the subfig documentation again :-) and found option: `font=<size>`, where you can select size from `\scriptsize` to `\Large`.

Comment: I tried that myself! Because of the noob I am, I did not know I needed to add the \. Thank you for that. However, when I add it, it tells me my TeX capacity is exceeded. Any way to work around this. Here's the error:

    "TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000]. \usepackage" 

The code I use is: 

    \usepackage[font=\Large,labelfont=bf,labelformat=simple]{subfig}

Thanks for all your help so far!

Comment: I'm very sorry to misleading you regarding font size (i didn't tested before posting). For font size you should use only `scriptsize` to `Large`. This work fine. For example, that you like to have Lare fonts for sub captions, than `\usepackage[labelfont=bf,labelformat=simple,font=Large]{subfig}` did the trick. Of course, you can use caption set up for settings of `subfig` options: `\captionsetup[subfloat]{labelfont=bf,labelformat=simple,font=Large}`.