# IEEEtran: Labeling top left without cutting in-between

Tags: floats, labels, subcaption, ieeetran

I'm trying to Label multiple figures on top left without cutting in-between figs, just like this:[image]

However, any code such as ["Subfigures. To add A and B to subfigures (in the top left corner), and to label them for referencing"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/310081/subfigures-to-add-a-and-b-to-subfigures-in-the-top-left-corner-and-to-label) didn't work. (The code vanishes all figs)
Is there anyone who make it this with IEEEtran ? Please give me any tip
FYI, my preamble and code.
Thank you

```
\documentclass[lettersize,journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[caption=false,font=normalsize,labelfont=sf,textfont=sf]{subfig}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{graphicx}%CAAAAAAUTION!!!!!!
\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor IEEE-Xplore}
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
\usepackage{balance}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!t]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=2.5in]{test-sine}
\includegraphics[width=2.5in]{test-cos}
\includegraphics[width=2.5in]{test-tan}
\caption{Hi}
\label{Test}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to crop yours image on the left with the option `trim={1 cm 0 0 0}`, where 1 cm is an example. Try with yours image. Here is one suggestion:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}%CAAAAAAUTION!!!!!!

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[!t]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[trim={2cm 0 0 0},clip, width=2.5in]{example-image-a}
        \includegraphics[width=2.5in]{example-image-a}
        \includegraphics[width=2.5in]{example-image-c}
        \caption{Hi}
        \label{Test}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! You helped me:)