# How to change last column width in a subtable using subcaption?

Tags: tables, tabularx, subcaption

I decided to write my Masters using LaTeX a week ago. I start from zero. I learn everything thanks to you and this forum. Please be indulgent and do not laugh at my code :-)
So, I am trying to create a table with 3 subtables. My problems are:

1. The last column of my first subtable is too long. I think this is due to my very long sentence in my last line. I cannot find a way to change its width.
2. I do not know what to use between tabular, tabularx, tabular* to change this width. I tried different things with tabularx and sub caption but nothing worked.
3. I would like to have the same width for the 3 subtables.
4. I would like to put the a), b), c) on the left and aligned with "Fixed effects" instead of above each subtable and centered.

Here is my code:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[french,english]{babel}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{table}}
\begin{table}[]
\caption{A first very long sentence. a) Name of my first subtable. b) Name of my second subtable. c) Name of my third subtable.}
\scriptsize
\centering
\begin{subtable}{0.9\textwidth}
\centering
\subcaption{}
\begin{tabular}{l c c c c}
\cline{1-5}
Fixed effects & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Estimate $\pm$ SE} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Z} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{P} \\
\cline{1-5}
(Intercept) & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.27 $\pm$ 0.13} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{-2.10} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.036} \\
Trial & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.00 $\pm$ 0.05} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{0.04} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.965} \\
\cline{1-5}
Random effects & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Variance $\pm$ SD} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{LRT} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{d.f.} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{P} \\
\cline{1-5}
Bird (intercept) & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.55 $\pm$ 0.74} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{159} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{< 0.001} \\
Bird (slope with trial) & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.02 $\pm$ 0.16} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{1.40} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.237} \\
Flock (intercept) & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.00 $\pm$ 0.00} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{1} \\
\cline{1-5}
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\multirow{2}{\linewidth}{N = 454. The response variable is the proportion of scrounged patches, expressed as a 2-column matrix composed of the number of scrounged patches and number of produced patches.}} \\
\multicolumn{5}{l}{} \\
\end{tabular}
\label{tbl:sub-table-a}
\end{subtable}      
\begin{subtable}{0.9\textwidth}
\centering
\subcaption{}
\begin{tabular}{l c c c c}
\cline{1-5}
Fixed effects & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Estimate $\pm$ SE} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Z} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{P} \\ 
\cline{1-5} 
(Intercept) & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.26 $\pm$ 0.19} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{-1.39} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.166} \\
Trial & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.04 $\pm$ 0.09} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{0.44} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.659} \\
\cline{1-5} 
Random effects & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Variance $\pm$ SD} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{LRT} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{d.f.} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{P} \\
\cline{1-5} 
Bird (intercept) & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.60 $\pm$ 0.77} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{81.2} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{< 0.001}     \\
Bird (slope with trial) & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.05 $\pm$ 0.22} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{1.68} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.194} \\
Flock (intercept) & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.00 $\pm$ 0.00} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{1} \\ 
\cline{1-5}  
\multicolumn{5}{l}{N = 234.} \\
\end{tabular}
\label{tbl:sub-table-b}
\end{subtable}
\begin{subtable}{0.9\textwidth}
\centering
\subcaption{}
\begin{tabular}{l c c c c}
\cline{1-5}
Fixed effects & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Estimate $\pm$ SE} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Z} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{P} \\ 
\cline{1-5} 
(Intercept) & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.27 $\pm$ 0.17} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{-1.57} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.117} \\
Trial & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.03 $\pm$ 0.07} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{-0.42} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.674} \\ 
\cline{1-5} 
Random effects & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Variance $\pm$ SD} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{LRT} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{d.f.} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{P} \\ 
\cline{1-5}
Bird (intercept) & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.50 $\pm$ 0.71} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{77.5} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{< 0.001} \\
Bird (slope with trial) & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.01 $\pm$ 0.10} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.17} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.682} \\
Flock (intercept) & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.00 $\pm$ 0.00} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{1} \\ 
\cline{1-5}  
\multicolumn{5}{l}{N = 220.} \\ 
\end{tabular}
\label{tbl:sub-table-c}
\end{subtable}
\label{tab:scrounging}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]
Thousand thanks for all your help! :-D

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You wrote "...I decided to write my Masters using LaTeX..." -- excellent decision!! :-)

Comment: Thank you Mico! I find this community extremely active. It is very inspiring and it validates my decision to learn LaTeX!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some suggestions, made in no particular order:

- Use the line-drawing macros of the `booktabs` package -- `\toprule`, `\midrule`, etc -- instead of `\hline` and `\cline` to get well-spaced horizontal lines.
- Using `\scriptsize` is bound to make readers squint, and possible want to skip ahead to other material. Don't go below `\footnotesize` if you expect your readers to spend some time taking in the tabular material.
- Use a common width of ca `0.7\textwidth` for each of the three `subtable` environments, and make sure that all three `tabular` environments have the same width; this may be achieved by using a `p{\textwidth}` directive for the final row in each `tabular` environment.
- Save yourself a lot of typing (all those `\multicolumn` directives must be getting old...) in the body of a `tabular` environment by setting up "smart", specifically, automatic math-mode columns for the 4 data columns. In the preamble below, look for how the `C` and `R` column types are defined.
- To left-justify the captions of the `subtable` environments, run an instruction such as

  ```
  \captionsetup[subtable]{singlelinecheck=false,justification=raggedright}
  ```

  Do use the same font size for the captions as you do for the embedded `tabular` environments.
- Unless you like to go on (code) scavenger hunts, do keep the `\caption` and associated `\label` directives together.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french,english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs,array,subcaption}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{$}c<{$}}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{$}r<{$}}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{table}}
\begin{table}
\footnotesize
\captionsetup[subtable]{size=footnotesize,
                        singlelinecheck=false,
                        justification=raggedright}
\caption{A first very long sentence. a) Name of my first subtable. 
b) Name of my second subtable. 
c) Name of my third subtable.} 
\label{tab:scrounging}

\centering % a single \centering instruction suffices

\begin{subtable}{0.7\textwidth}
\caption{} \label{tbl:sub-table-a}
\begin{tabular}{@{}lCRCR@{}}
\toprule
Fixed effects & \text{Estimate} \pm \text{SE} & \multicolumn{2}{C}{Z} & P \\
\midrule
(Intercept) & -0.27 \pm 0.13 & \multicolumn{2}{C}{-2.10} & 0.036 \\
Trial       & \phantom{-}0.00 \pm 0.05 & \multicolumn{2}{C}{\phantom{-}0.04} & 0.965 \\
\midrule
Random effects & \text{Variance} \pm \text{SD} & \text{LRT} & \text{d.f.} & P \\
\midrule
Bird (intercept) & 0.55 \pm 0.74 & 159 & 1 & < 0.001 \\
Bird (slope with trial) & 0.02 \pm 0.16 & 1.40 & 1 & 0.237 \\
Flock (intercept) & 0.00 \pm 0.00 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{5}{@{}p{\textwidth}@{}}{$N = 454$. The response variable is 
the proportion of scrounged patches, expressed as a 2-column matrix 
composed of the number of scrounged patches and number of produced patches.} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{subtable}   

\bigskip % insert some space between the subtables
\begin{subtable}{0.7\textwidth}
\subcaption{} \label{tbl:sub-table-b}
\begin{tabular}{@{}lCRCR@{}}
\toprule
Fixed effects & \text{Estimate} \pm \text{SE} & \multicolumn{2}{C}{Z} & P \\ 
\midrule 
(Intercept) & -0.26 \pm 0.19 & \multicolumn{2}{C}{-1.39} & 0.166 \\
Trial & \phantom{-}0.04 \pm 0.09 & \multicolumn{2}{C}{\phantom{-}0.44} & 0.659 \\
\midrule 
Random effects & \text{Variance} \pm \text{SD} & \text{LRT} & \text{d.f.} & P \\
\midrule 
Bird (intercept) & 0.60 \pm 0.77 & 81.2 & 1 & < 0.001 \\
Bird (slope with trial) & 0.05 \pm 0.22 & 1.68 & 1 & 0.194 \\
Flock (intercept) & 0.00 \pm 0.00 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 
\midrule  
\multicolumn{5}{@{}p{\textwidth}@{}}{$N = 234$.} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{subtable}

\bigskip
\begin{subtable}{0.7\textwidth}
\subcaption{} \label{tbl:sub-table-c}
\begin{tabular}{@{}lCRCR@{}}
\toprule
Fixed effects & \text{Estimate}\pm\text{SE} & \multicolumn{2}{C}{Z} & P \\ 
\midrule 
(Intercept) & -0.27 \pm 0.17 & \multicolumn{2}{C}{-1.57} & 0.117 \\
Trial & -0.03 \pm 0.07 & \multicolumn{2}{C}{-0.42} & 0.674 \\ 
\midrule 
Random effects & \text{Variance}\pm\text{SD} & \text{LRT} & \text{d.f.} & P \\ 
\midrule
Bird (intercept) & 0.50 \pm 0.71 & 77.5 & 1 & < 0.001 \\
Bird (slope with trial) & 0.01 \pm 0.10 & 0.17 & 1 & 0.682 \\
Flock (intercept) & 0.00 \pm 0.00 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 
\midrule  
\multicolumn{5}{@{}p{\textwidth}@{}}{$N = 220$.} \\ 
\end{tabular}
\end{subtable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

---

---

*Addendum* to address the first of the OP's follow-up questions: If you want to make the "gaps" between the columns equally wide, I suggest you use `tabular*` environments, as shown in the following code. The somewhat unwieldy-looking directive `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}` directive tells LaTeX to increase the intercolumn whitespace to fill up the available space.

Note that I also suggest moving the common legend to a place above the subtables.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french,english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,booktabs,array,subcaption}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{$}c<{$}}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{$}r<{$}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\captionsetup[subtable]{size=footnotesize,
                        skip=0.25\baselineskip,
                        singlelinecheck=false,
                        justification=raggedright}
\caption{A first very long sentence. 
    a) Name of my first subtable. 
    b) Name of my second subtable. 
    c) Name of my third subtable.} 
\label{tab:scrounging}

\footnotesize

\bigskip
In the following tables, the response variable is the proportion of scrounged patches, expressed as a 2-column matrix  composed of the number of scrounged patches and number of produced patches.

\centering % a single \centering instruction suffices
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % let LaTeX figure out the intercolumn spacing

\bigskip
\begin{subtable}{0.7\textwidth}
\caption{} \label{tbl:sub-table-a}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lCRCR}
\toprule
Fixed effects & \text{Estimate} \pm \text{SE} & \multicolumn{2}{C}{Z} & P \\
\midrule
(Intercept) & -0.27 \pm 0.13 & \multicolumn{2}{C}{-2.10} & 0.036 \\
Trial       & \phantom{-}0.00 \pm 0.05 & \multicolumn{2}{C}{\phantom{-}0.04} & 0.965 \\
\midrule
Random effects & \text{Variance} \pm \text{SD} & \text{LRT} & \text{d.f.} & P \\
\midrule
Bird (intercept) & 0.55 \pm 0.74 & 159 & 1 & < 0.001 \\
Bird (slope with trial) & 0.02 \pm 0.16 & 1.40 & 1 & 0.237 \\
Flock (intercept) & 0.00 \pm 0.00 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
\midrule
$N = 454$. \\
\end{tabular*}
\end{subtable}   

\bigskip % insert some space between the subtables
\begin{subtable}{0.7\textwidth}
\subcaption{} \label{tbl:sub-table-b}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lCRCR}
\toprule
Fixed effects & \text{Estimate} \pm \text{SE} & \multicolumn{2}{C}{Z} & P \\ 
\midrule 
(Intercept) & -0.26 \pm 0.19 & \multicolumn{2}{C}{-1.39} & 0.166 \\
Trial & \phantom{-}0.04 \pm 0.09 & \multicolumn{2}{C}{\phantom{-}0.44} & 0.659 \\
\midrule 
Random effects & \text{Variance} \pm \text{SD} & \text{LRT} & \text{d.f.} & P \\
\midrule 
Bird (intercept) & 0.60 \pm 0.77 & 81.2 & 1 & < 0.001 \\
Bird (slope with trial) & 0.05 \pm 0.22 & 1.68 & 1 & 0.194 \\
Flock (intercept) & 0.00 \pm 0.00 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 
\midrule  
$N = 234$. \\
\end{tabular*}
\end{subtable}

\bigskip
\begin{subtable}{0.7\textwidth}
\subcaption{} \label{tbl:sub-table-c}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lCRCR}
\toprule
Fixed effects & \text{Estimate}\pm\text{SE} & \multicolumn{2}{C}{Z} & P \\ 
\midrule 
(Intercept) & -0.27 \pm 0.17 & \multicolumn{2}{C}{-1.57} & 0.117 \\
Trial & -0.03 \pm 0.07 & \multicolumn{2}{C}{-0.42} & 0.674 \\ 
\midrule 
Random effects & \text{Variance}\pm\text{SD} & \text{LRT} & \text{d.f.} & P \\ 
\midrule
Bird (intercept) & 0.50 \pm 0.71 & 77.5 & 1 & < 0.001 \\
Bird (slope with trial) & 0.01 \pm 0.10 & 0.17 & 1 & 0.682 \\
Flock (intercept) & 0.00 \pm 0.00 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 
\midrule  
$N = 220$. \\ 
\end{tabular*}
\end{subtable}

\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for all these suggestions! :-D It is so beautiful! I will come back in a few days with new more questions haha. Thank you!!

Comment: Well, I have 3 more questions...:
First, is there a mean to have similar gaps between Estimate ± SE and Z, and between Z and P? Same question with Variance ± SD and LRT, LRT and d.f., d.f. and P.
Second, is there a mean to put (a), (b), (c) on the same line as Fixed effects?
Third, when I use ‘showframe‘, a part of my third subtable is out of the page. Is there a mean to control all the table length?
Thanks a lot in advance! :-)

Comment: @Bateau - You now have enough reputation points to upvote answers you find useful -- not only on your own postings, by the way. You are also free to "accept" (by clicking on the checkmark symbol) an answer to a question of yours that you find most useful. Incidentally, since your new questions are only loosely related to your previous posting, you should post a *new query*. That way, it'll be seen by a lot more people who may be able to offer a solution. By the way, what do you mean by "Is there a mean..."? Do you maybe mean, "Is there a method..."?

Comment: Thank you for these tips! I'll use my new powers for sure!
Yes I meant is there a method to divide more equitably the gap between each column? I don't understand why the last column takes all the width available...

Comment: @Bateau - I'll provide an addendum to my answer to address your first follow-up question. For the second follow-up question, please search this site for methods for placing labels in the margins. Regarding your third follow-up question: Since you haven't told us anything about the size of  the textblock of your document, I can't give you any concrete advice on what to do. For sure, the entire `table` environment produced in the answer above fits comfortably in the (default) textblock.

Comment: Thanks for the addendum! It's exactly what I wanted :-D 
I'm using memoireuqam1.3 which is a document class for Masters at UQAM. It is built on a report document class. But I don't really know much more about it.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**
You have partly right :) last `multicolum` row is to wide. It is defined with `linewidth`, which defined with width of `subtable`. If you shorten it to 77mm, the table will appear as you wish.

[image]

Regarding `subcaption` position, I understand, that you like to have them left of table, aligned with first table row. This can be achieved with use of `floatrow` and use `subfig` package instead of `subcaption`.

I now also exploit presence of `booktabs` for horizontal rule and add `makecell` for defining column's heads with its macro `thead`.

For equal width of all sub tables is sensible to use tables' environments with prescribed width as they are `tabularx` and `tabular*`. Use of `tabular is simpler. For their width I suggest to define new length (see MWE below) by which you can set all sub tables width in one place.

In estimation of appropriate table width I help myself with `showframe` package which show page layout. Of course, in final document this package had to be removed from preamble.

*Of-topic:* 
your table is unnecessary complicated. I remove all of `multicolumn`s  except those which span two columns. Also tables with font size `\script` is difficult to read, so I suggest to use bigger ones.

Complete, new MWE which contain only the first table, is:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[french,english]{babel}

\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}% <--- added makecell
    \renewcommand\theadfont{\footnotesize}
    \newcommand\mc[2]{\multicolumn{#1}{c}{#2}}
    \newcommand\mr[1]{\multicolumn{1}{r}{#1}}
    \newlength\tabwidth
\usepackage{floatrow}% <-- added for side position of subcaptions
\floatsetup[table]{style=plain,subcapbesideposition=top,capposition=top}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[label font=bf,labelformat=parens]{subfig}
\usepackage{calc}% <-- added for calculation of cell width

\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[]
\caption{A first very long sentence. a) Name of my first subtable. b) Name of my second subtable. c) Name of my third subtable.}
    \label{tbl:sub-table-a}
\centering
\setlength\tabwidth{90mm}
\footnotesize
\sidesubfloat[]{
\begin{tabularx}{\tabwidth}{X c c c r}
    \toprule
\thead{Fixed effects}
                & \thead{Estimate $\pm$ SE}
                                    & \mc{2}{\thead{Z}}     & \thead{P} \\
    \midrule
(Intercept)     & -0.27 $\pm$ 0.13  & \mc{2}{-2.10} & 0.036             \\
Trial           & 0.00 $\pm$ 0.05   & \mc{2}{0.04}  & 0.965             \\
    \midrule
\thead{Random effects}
                & \thead{Variance $\pm$ SD} 
                                    & \thead{LRT}   & \thead{d.f.}  
                                                            & \thead{P} \\
    \midrule
Bird (intercept)& 0.55 $\pm$ 0.74   & \mr{159}      & 1     & $<$ 0.001 \\
Bird (slope with trial)
                & 0.02 $\pm$ 0.16   & \mr{1.40}     & 1     &  0.237    \\
Flock (intercept)
                & 0.00 $\pm$ 0.00   & \mr{0}        & 1     & 1         \\
    \midrule[1pt]
\multicolumn{5}{p{\tabwidth-2\tabcolsep}}{N = 454. The response variable is the proportion of scrounged patches, expressed as a 2-column matrix composed of the number of scrounged patches and number of produced patches.}
\end{tabularx}
}   
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! May I ask you why the right width is 77mm? What calculation did you make? :-)
And last thing, how could I put the a), b), c) at the left, aligned with "Fixed effects" please? Again, thanks a lot! :-D

Comment: to much questions ... :). (i) if you add `showframe` package (it show page layout) in preamble of your document, than is not difficult to estimate table width, (ii) this question was asked before: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20354/ .

Comment: Ok for the showframe, but did you try 80mm, 79mm, 78mm, etc... or did you do a calculation that I miss? :-)
Thanks for the other link!

Comment: 77 is magic number: you need to stroke twice the same key :). well, 80 mm is also fine. See edit of my answer.

Comment: Haha it is a good point for 77. Thanks Zarko for the addendum, I will take a closer look at it :-)

Answer (score 0):

A solution with `tabularx` and `siunitx`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%
 \usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[french,english]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx, siunitx}
\sisetup{table-number-alignment=center}
\usepackage{caption, subcaption}
\captionsetup{font=small}
\captionsetup[subtable]{singlelinecheck=off, font=footnotesize}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!htbp]
  \caption{A first very long sentence. a) Name of my first subtable. b) Name of my second subtable. c) Name of my third subtable.}
  \footnotesize\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
  \centering
  \begin{subtable}{0.65\textwidth}
    \subcaption{}\label{tbl:sub-table-a}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{X S[table-format=-1.2, separate-uncertainty, table-figures-uncertainty=2] c c S[table-format=1.3, table-comparator]}
      \toprule
      Fixed effects & {Estimate $\pm$ SE} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Z} & {P} \\
      \midrule %
      (Intercept) & -0.27(13) & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$-2.10 $} & 0.036 \\%
      Trial & 0.00(05) & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\phantom{-} 0.04 $} & 0.965 \\
      \midrule
      Random effects & {Variance $\pm$ SD} & LRT & d.f. & {P} \\
      \midrule
      Bird (intercept) & 0.55(74) & \multicolumn{1}{r}{159} & 1 & {}< 0.001 \\%
      Bird (slope with trial) & 0.02(16) & \multicolumn{1}{r}{1.40} & 1 & 0.237 \\%
      Flock (intercept) & 0.00(0) & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0} & 1 & {1} \\
      \bottomrule
      \addlinespace[1ex]
      \multicolumn{5}{@{}p{\linewidth}@{}}{N = 454. The response variable is the proportion of scrounged patches, expressed as a 2-column matrix composed of the number of scrounged patches and number of produced patches.\medskip}
    \end{tabularx}
  \end{subtable}

  \begin{subtable}{0.65\textwidth}
    \subcaption{}\label{tbl:sub-table-b}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{X S[table-format=-1.2, separate-uncertainty, table-figures-uncertainty=2] c c S[table-format=1.3, table-comparator]}
      \toprule
      Fixed effects & {Estimate $\pm$ SE} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Z} & {P} \\
      \midrule %
      (Intercept) & -0.26(19) & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$ -1.39 $} & 0.166 \\%
      Trial & 0.00(05) & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\phantom{-} 0.44 $} & 0.659 \\
      \midrule
      Random effects & {Variance $\pm$ SD} & LRT & d.f. & {P} \\
      \midrule
      Bird (intercept) & 0.60(77) & \multicolumn{1}{r}{81.2} & 1 & < 0.001 \\%
      Bird (slope with trial) & 0.05(22) & \multicolumn{1}{r}{1.68} & 1 & 0.194 \\%
      Flock (intercept) & 0.00(0) & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0} & 1 & {1} \\
      \bottomrule
      \addlinespace[1ex]
      \multicolumn{5}{@{}p{\linewidth}@{}}{N =234.\medskip}
    \end{tabularx}
  \end{subtable}

  \begin{subtable}{0.65\textwidth}
    \subcaption{}\label{tbl:sub-table-c}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{X S[table-format=-1.2, separate-uncertainty, table-figures-uncertainty=2] c c S[table-format=1.3, table-comparator]}
      \toprule
      Fixed effects & {Estimate $\pm$ SE} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Z} & {P} \\
      \midrule %
      (Intercept) & -0.27(17) & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$ -1.57 $} & 0.117 \\%
      Trial & -0.03(07) & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$ -0.42 $} & 0.674 \\
      \midrule
      Random effects & {Variance $\pm$ SD} & LRT & d.f. & {P} \\
      \midrule
      Bird (intercept) & 0.50(71) & \multicolumn{1}{r}{77.5} & 1 & < 0.001 \\%
      Bird (slope with trial) & 0.01(10) & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.17} & 1 & 0.682 \\%
      Flock (intercept) & 0.00(0) & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0} & 1 & {1} \\
      \bottomrule
      \addlinespace[1ex]
      \multicolumn{5}{@{}p{\linewidth}@{}}{N =220.}
    \end{tabularx}
  \end{subtable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]