# Add axis label to subfloat images

Tags: graphics, floats, subfloats, axis

I need to set an x-label and a y-label to each subfigure, can I add labels to \subloat[]?

```
\begin{figure}[H]%
    \centering
    \subfloat[]{{\includegraphics[width=6.75cm]{ProfitV1.png}}}%
    \qquad
    \subfloat[]{{\includegraphics[width=6.75cm]{StockV1.png}}}%
    \qquad
    \subfloat[]{{\includegraphics[width=6.75cm]{PoliciesSV1.png}}}%
    \qquad
    \subfloat[]{{\includegraphics[width=6.75cm]{PoliciesMV1.png}}}%
    \qquad
    \subfloat[]{{\includegraphics[width=6.75cm]{PoliciesLV1.png}}}%
    \vspace{-5pt}
    \caption{Caption.}%
    \label{resultsV1}%
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!  Please, explain what should be contents of "labels" and how they should be positioned at image. As far as I know, `\subfloat` is intended for sub captions belo images and `\sidesubfloat` from `floatrow` at side of  image (see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20354).

Comment: See if the following helps/clarify your question:  `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo,
            export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]%
    \centering
    \subfloat[sub caption (for referencing image)]{
        \begin{tabular}{c@{\,}c}
        y label & \includegraphics[width=6.75cm,valign=c]{ProfitV1}\\
                &   x label
        \end{tabular}}
     \caption{Caption.}
    \label{resultsV1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
`