# Side caption on subfigure

Tags: pdftex, captions, sidecap

I have problem: I would like to put a side caption on a subfigure.
Here is my actual code (that doesn't perform the side caption):

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{center}
    \subfigure[\footnotesize{...}]{
        \label{...}
        \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{...}
    }
    \subfigure[\footnotesize{...}]{
        \label{...}
        \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{...}
    }\\
    \subfigure[\footnotesize{...}]{
        \label{...}
        \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{...}
    }
    \subfigure[\footnotesize{...}]{
        \label{...}
        \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{...}
    }\\
    \subfigure[\footnotesize{...}]{
        \label{...}
        \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{...}
    }
    \subfigure[\footnotesize{...}]{
        \label{...}
        \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{...}
    }\\
    \subfigure[\footnotesize{...}]{
        \label{...}
        \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{...}
    }
    \subfigure[\footnotesize{...}]{
        \label{...}
        \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{...}
    }\\
    \subfigure[\footnotesize{...}]{
        \label{...}
        \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{...}
    }
    \subfigure[\footnotesize{...}]{
        \label{...}
        \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{...}
    }\\
\end{center}
\caption{"I would like that this text is put on the side of the image"}
\label{...}
\end{figure}
```

Where I put "..." is text that I delete.
I tried with the `sidecap` package and edit the environment with `SCfigure` instead of `figure`, but this gives me a lot of errors.

Comment: The  subfigures have no individual (sub)captions?

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20354, if this can help you

Comment: subfigures only have labels.
The question related you posted doesn't concern what I really want to do.. in the code where there is caption tag you can find what I'm trying to do

Comment: The subfigure package is no longer supported.  You can use \subfloat from the subcaption package instead.

Comment: You have 10 images; what image would you put the caption next to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, be aware that `subfigure` is obsolete. Either use `subfig` (and `\subfloat` instead of `\subfigure`) or the more recent and maintained `subcaption` package.

I *guess* that you want the caption to be next to the set of images because the caption text is long. Otherwise bottom placement would be much better.

Just use a `tabular` to align the images and a minipage to set the caption.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock caption text

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{tabular}{@{}cc@{}}
    \subfloat[subfigure]{%
        \label{a}%
        \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{example-image}%
    }&
    \subfloat[subfigure]{%
        \label{b}%
        \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{example-image}%
    }\\
    \subfloat[subfigure]{%
        \label{c}%
        \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{example-image}%
    }&
    \subfloat[subfigure]{%
        \label{d}%
        \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{example-image}%
    }\\
    \subfloat[subfigure]{%
        \label{e}%
        \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{example-image}%
    }&
    \subfloat[subfigure]{%
        \label{f}%
        \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{example-image}%
    }\\
    \subfloat[subfigure]{%
        \label{g}%
        \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{example-image}%
    }&
    \subfloat[subfigure]{%
        \label{h}%
        \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{example-image}%
    }\\
    \subfloat[subfigure]{%
        \label{i}%
        \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{example-image}%
    }&
    \subfloat[subfigure]{%
        \label{j}%
        \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{example-image}%
    }\\
\end{tabular}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\caption{\lipsum[2]}
\label{x}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Using `[H]` as the placement specifier is generally wrong; even more in this case where the float is quite large.

[image]

With a couple of tricks you can get top alignment.

1. change `\begin{tabular}{@{}cc@{}}` into

   ```
   \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}cc@{}} \\[-\dp\strutbox]
   ```
2. change `\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}` into

   ```
   \begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
   ```

The rest remains unchanged.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. That's exactly what I wanted to do!!!

Answer (score 1):

This differs from sidecap in that it computes the width available for the caption and it aligns the tops using `\raisebox`.

The caption `\label` should go inside the minipage with the caption.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htp]
\sbox0{\begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}% get width of combined subfigures
    \subfigure[\footnotesize{...}]{
        \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{example-image}
    }
    \subfigure[\footnotesize{...}]{
        \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{example-image}
    }\\
    \subfigure[\footnotesize{...}]{
        \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{example-image}
    }
    \subfigure[\footnotesize{...}]{
        \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{example-image}
    }\\
    \subfigure[\footnotesize{...}]{
        \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{example-image}
    }
    \subfigure[\footnotesize{...}]{
        \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{example-image}
    }\\
    \subfigure[\footnotesize{...}]{
        \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{example-image}
    }
    \subfigure[\footnotesize{...}]{
        \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{example-image}
    }\\
    \subfigure[\footnotesize{...}]{
        \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{example-image}
    }
    \subfigure[\footnotesize{...}]{
        \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{example-image}
    }\\
\end{varwidth}}%
\raisebox{-\height}{\usebox0}% left
\hspace{\columnsep}% gap
\raisebox{-\height}{\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr \textwidth-\wd0-\columnsep}
\abovecaptionskip=0pt
\caption{"I would like that this text is put on the side of the image"}
\end{minipage}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```