# floatrow, caption does not fill the dedicated space

Tags: floatrow

I'm using the floatrow package to get caption beside figures. Here is a sample code example:

```
\lipsum[3]
\lipsum[3]
\lipsum[3]

\begin{figure}[htb!]
\floatbox[{\capbeside\thisfloatsetup{capbesideposition={left,center},capbesidewidth=sidefil}}]{figure}[\FBwidth]
{\caption{\textbf{My caption does not fit the whole width, My caption does not fit the whole width, My caption does not fit the whole width} }\label{dz0_pot_lbd}}
{\includegraphics[width=0.475\textwidth]{dz0_pot_lbd.png}}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[3]
\lipsum[3]
\lipsum[3]
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Please note that I'm using [this template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/tub-phdthesistemplate/dkcxgddksgzk), if you want to reproduce this error, you would have to add `\usepackage{floatrow}` in thesis.tex.

From my understanding `capbesidewidth=sidefil` should make sure that caption uses all the box space not used by the image. But somehow there is still some few unused blank on the left (see red annotations above). I tried to manually set capbesidewidth to some increasing values, but this just pushes the image on the right side. Using `\fcapside[\FBwidth]` instead of `\floatbox` does also not work. Could it be that the full size box is just not set to \textwidth?

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: You don't need to use floatrow to put captions beside images, it just takes a little work.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/525478/side-caption-on-subfigure for example.