# How to place captions beside figure?

Tags: tables, floats

I have a table with 2 figures in each cell.

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{mnist/1.png}& \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{mnist/2.png}\\
\end{tabular}
\caption{Results on the moving mnist dataset}
\label{fig:qualitativemnist}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

But I would like additional captions like below

[image]

What is the easiest way to do it ? I have tried it this way but the output is not correct

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
asd\\asd\\asd\\asd\\asd\\asd&
\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{mnist/1.png}& \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{mnist/2.png}\\
\end{tabular}
\caption{Prediction examples on the moving mnist dataset}
\label{fig:qualitativemnist}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: If I correctly understood your question, than you firs need for each row on image new image which you include in figure by use of `floatrow` package. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20354/.

Answer (score 2):

Matching the row spacing of an image will be hit or miss, as will adjusting the position within each row.  Images have their baselines at the very bottom, hence the [b] tabulars.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t]
\centering
\def\arraystretch{1.2}% controls row spacing
\raisebox{1ex}{\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}c@{}}% contols row centering
asd\\asd\\asd\\asd\\asd\\asd
\end{tabular}}
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{mnist/1.png}\hfil
\raisebox{1ex}{\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}c@{}}
asd\\asd\\asd\\asd\\asd\\asd
\end{tabular}}
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{mnist/2.png}
\caption{Prediction examples on the moving mnist dataset}% automatic \par
\label{fig:qualitativemnist}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: that looks very complicated. thank you