# Placing text outside the plot with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, annotations

[image]

I would like to have the text like '(a)' in the position outside the plot next to the x-ticks in a Tikzpicture. I tried saving the plot generated by matplotlib in tikz format, and use that in Latex file. However the text disappears when it is outside the plot

The tikzpicture file which I saved from Matplotlib is given by :

````
\begin{tikzpicture}

\definecolor{color0}{rgb}{0.12156862745098,0.466666666666667,0.705882352941177}
\definecolor{color1}{rgb}{1,0.498039215686275,0.0549019607843137}

\begin{axis}[
height=\figH,
tick align=outside,
tick pos=left,
width=\figW,
x grid style={white!69.0196078431373!black},
xmajorgrids,
xmin=-4.44444444444444e-05, xmax=0.000933333333333333,
xtick style={color=black},
y grid style={white!69.0196078431373!black},
ymajorgrids,
ymin=0.125777210945621, ymax=0.82064477120417,
ytick style={color=black}
]
\addplot [semithick, color0]
table {%
0 0.157362100048282
0.000222222222222222 0.231964290056153
0.000444444444444444 0.789059882101509
0.000666666666666667 0.661985011331508
0.000888888888888889 0.176917594785121
};
\addplot [semithick, color1, mark=asterisk, mark size=3, mark options={solid}, only marks]
table {%
0 0.309631433514708
0.000222222222222222 0.356544604589611
0.000444444444444444 0.403457775664515
0.000666666666666667 0.450370946739418
0.000888888888888889 0.497284117814321
};
\end{axis}

\draw ({$(current bounding box.south west)!0.02!(current bounding box.south east)$}|-{$(current bounding box.south west)!0.9!(current bounding box.north west)$}) node[
  scale=0.7,
  anchor=base west,
  text=black,
  rotate=0.0
]{(a)};
\end{tikzpicture}```
````

Comment: Please. Gives a MWE...

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: What is meaning of `(a)`? If this is sub-caption label, than write it as part of sub-figure environment, as is done in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20354/, if not, add it to image as `ylabel` accordingly positioned.

Comment: @Zarko ! Thank you for your suggestion with sub-figure environment. I have tried it. However it takes up horizontal space.

Comment: @Zarko! The '(a)' is just to name the figures since they are presented in a 4x2 array format. I would like to have '(a)' till '(e)', and place them in line with the x-ticks. Could you tell me how to achieve this ?

Comment: Please extend your code sniped to complete small document with array of images. So far we haven't any information about your images layout nor about used packages. Knowing this we will can far easily help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**
Slightly improved images styles and positioning of pictures layout.

If I understood your question and comments to it correctly, than you after for something like this:

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)

Above image is produced by:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
    \begin{filecontents}{data.dat}
x                    y1                y2
0                    0.157362100048282 0.309631433514708
0.000222222222222222 0.231964290056153 0.356544604589611
0.000444444444444444 0.789059882101509 0.403457775664515
0.000666666666666667 0.661985011331508 0.450370946739418
0.000888888888888889 0.176917594785121 0.497284117814321
    \end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize, label font=bf]{subfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\floatsetup[figure]{style=plain,capbesidewidth=-1em,
                    subcapbesideposition=bottom}

%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}% For dummy text. Don't use in a real document


\begin{document}    
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\pgfplotsset{
    width=0.4\linewidth, height=0.2\textheight,
    scale only axis,
    tick align=outside, tick pos=left,
        tick style = {semithick, tickwidth=1mm}, % added
    grid,
    grid style={very thin, gray!30},
    enlarge x limits =0.04,
    xmin=0, xmax=0.0009,
    xtick={0,0.0002,...,0.0008},
    scaled x ticks=false,
    xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/.cd,
            fixed, precision=4},
    ymin=0, ymax=0.95,
    ytick={0,0.1,...,0.9},
    tick label style={font=\scriptsize, inner xsep=1pt}
        }
        
\sidesubfloat[]{\hspace{-1em}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}            ]
\addplot +[semithick] table [y=y1]{data.dat};
\addplot +[semithick,
           mark=asterisk, only marks] table [y=y2]{data.dat};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
}\hfill
\sidesubfloat[]{\hspace{-1em}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}            ]
\addplot +[semithick] table [y=y1]{data.dat};
\addplot +[semithick,
           mark=asterisk, only marks] table [y=y2]{data.dat};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\medskip
\sidesubfloat[]{\hspace{-1em}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}            ]
\addplot +[semithick] table [y=y1]{data.dat};
\addplot +[semithick,
           mark=asterisk, only marks] table [y=y2]{data.dat};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
}\hfill
\sidesubfloat[]{\hspace{-1em}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot +[semithick] table [y=y1]{data.dat};
\addplot +[semithick,
           mark=asterisk, only marks] table [y=y2]{data.dat};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\medskip
\sidesubfloat[]{\hspace{-1em}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}            ]
\addplot +[semithick] table [y=y1]{data.dat};
\addplot +[semithick,
           mark=asterisk, only marks] table [y=y2]{data.dat};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
}\hfill
\sidesubfloat[]{\hspace{-1em}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot +[semithick] table [y=y1]{data.dat};
\addplot +[semithick,
           mark=asterisk, only marks] table [y=y2]{data.dat};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\medskip
\sidesubfloat[]{\hspace{-0.75em}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}            ]
\addplot +[semithick] table [y=y1]{data.dat};
\addplot +[semithick,
           mark=asterisk, only marks] table [y=y2]{data.dat};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
}\hfill
\sidesubfloat[]{\hspace{-0.75em}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot +[semithick] table [y=y1]{data.dat};
\addplot +[semithick,
           mark=asterisk, only marks] table [y=y2]{data.dat};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
    \caption{Image}
    \label{fig.sicaptions}
\end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

Of course, you need insert correct image code to each `\sidesubfloat`. Hopefully they all have the same settings.

Comment: +1 for solution, but looking at e.g. `(c)`, I can not see if the belonging graph is above or below. (I realise that you are not the one wishing to do it like this).

Comment: @hpekristiansen, sorry, I do not understand your comment. I only show possibilities how to add caption labels to OP images. I didn't express any my preferences about positioning of caption labels. Now are (more or les) in line with `xtick` labels, as OP request in his/her comment. Separation between rows with images can be increased by replacing `\medskip` with `\bigskip` or with `\vspace{<desired distance>}`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see: if you want to move your "(a)" label where you want, I'd do:

1. be sure to use a `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}` or higher (we don't know because your snippet is not complete);
2. add to the options `clip mode=individual`, so that nodes or lines that you add are not clipped out;
3. add the `\node` *inside* the axis environment. If you use the `rel axis cs:` coordinate system, you can use a `0,0` as the bottom left and `(1,1)` as the top right. Add the option you want to the node; I put mine here at `(0,1)` (top left), aligned `above left` with no separation and filling its background white.

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}% > 1.11!!!
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
   \definecolor{color0}{rgb}{0.12156862745098,0.466666666666667,0.705882352941177}
\definecolor{color1}{rgb}{1,0.498039215686275,0.0549019607843137}

\begin{axis}[
tick align=outside,
tick pos=left,
x grid style={white!69.0196078431373!black},
xmajorgrids,
xmin=-4.44444444444444e-05, xmax=0.000933333333333333,
xtick style={color=black},
y grid style={white!69.0196078431373!black},
ymajorgrids,
ymin=0.125777210945621, ymax=0.82064477120417,
ytick style={color=black},
%%% added
clip mode=individual
%%%
]
\addplot [semithick, color0]
table {%
0 0.157362100048282
0.000222222222222222 0.231964290056153
0.000444444444444444 0.789059882101509
0.000666666666666667 0.661985011331508
0.000888888888888889 0.176917594785121
};
\addplot [semithick, color1, mark=asterisk, mark size=3, mark options={solid}, only marks]
table {%
0 0.309631433514708
0.000222222222222222 0.356544604589611
0.000444444444444444 0.403457775664515
0.000666666666666667 0.450370946739418
0.000888888888888889 0.497284117814321
};
%%%
%%%added
\node[fill=white, inner sep=0pt, above left] at (rel axis cs:0,1) {\textbf{(a)}}; 
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

PS: notice that this *is* a correct [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: You can also use `\path  (rel axis cs:0,1) coordinate (aux);
\end{axis} \node[fill=white, inner sep=0pt, above left]  {\textbf{(a)}} at (aux);`, then there is not need to change the clipping, which is sometimes needed to produce the plot one wants.